# Command works on heroku command line but not in the pushed docker image

Tags: docker, clojure, leiningen

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install wget\
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein \
    && chmod a+x lein \
    && cp lein /usr/bin 

RUN "lein -v"
```

to download lein from the url, and put it in /usr/bin. But still the

`RUN lein -v`

command doesn't work.

I get the error:

```
remote: Step 18/22 : RUN lein -v        
remote:  ---> Running in e5f404275fe2        
remote: /bin/sh: 1: lein -v: not found        
remote: The command '/bin/sh -c lein -v' returned a non-zero code: 127        
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to appname
```

On Heroku one-off dyno itself, the command works.

$ /bin/sh -c "lein -v"

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that docker `RUN` expects the command unquoted, as is, or as an array of command and its args:

one of `RUN lein -v` or `RUN ["lein", "-v"]` should do the trick.

the other problem, that your image doesn't have java installed, so the command would fail anyway. So you need to install it somehow. Your final Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install wget\
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein \
    && chmod a+x lein \
    && cp lein /usr/bin 

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get -y install default-jre-headless && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN ["lein", "-v"]
```

-- EDIT --

In fact, adding the java dependency and changing to `RUN ["lein", "-v"]` doesn't work either. These are the first fifteen steps of the Dockerfile:

```
ARG CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION=1.10.1.507

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install curl wget bzip2 openjdk-8-jdk-headless\
    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    #    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp /usr/local \
    && rm -rf /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update conda \
    && curl -o install-clojure https://download.clojure.org/install/linux-install-${CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION}.sh \
    && chmod +x install-clojure \
    && ./install-clojure && rm install-clojure \
    # no need to install lein
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein > /usr/bin/lein \
    && chmod 777 /usr/bin/lein \
    


    && apt-get -qq -y autoremove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/log/dpkg.log \
    && conda clean --all --yes

ENV PATH /usr/bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_VERSION=12.18.1
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version


    

# ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# RUN conda create -n pyclj python=3.7 && conda install -n pyclj numpy mxnet \
#     && conda install -c conda-forge opencv
# ## To install pip packages into the pyclj environment do
# RUN conda run -n pyclj python3 -mpip install numpy opencv-python

FROM openjdk:8-alpine

RUN ["lein", "-v"]
```

and it gives the error

```
remote: Step 15/19 : RUN ["lein", "-v"]        
remote:  ---> Running in b817213d45b5        
remote: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"lein\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown        
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to
```

Comment: This is a part of a dockerfile so I was expecting the lein command to fail on java not found rather than lein not found. Is there a better way to run parts of a Dockerfile since running the whole Dockerfile for debugging would take four times as long?

Comment: the problem is not 'lein not found' , but rather `"lein -v"` not found, since the docker thinks it is a single executable. `RUN "lein"` works, but correct one (and recommended afaik) is `RUN ["lein", "-v"]`

Comment: you can debug it with by leaving the parts you need, and experimenting inside container, like comment RUN "lein -v" in your dockerfile, build it, then enter the containers shell docker run -ti ${container_id} /bin/sh and try to run some commands there. Also, the parts above your change in dockertile shouldn't be rebuilt, so actually it shouldn't be that long every time i guess. Like if you change the last RUN command now, it should be rebuilt quite fast.

Comment: RUN ["lein", "-v"] didn't work. My edit has (almost) the whole dockerfile

Comment: It does have the comma in the actual file

Comment: that is weird, are you sure the rest of your file is the same as in your question. because for me changing the last line in your file runs ok: it initializes leiningen, downloads jar and fails cause there is no java. what if you remove the last "RUN', then `docker build .` and then `docker run %your_image% lein` ?